# Why does java swing's setVisible take so long?

Tags: java, swing, visibility

I am writing a JPanel that is loading labels in a flowlayout whose information is taken from a database table's column.  I don't believe this is relevant though, because loading the data does not take long, only "setVisible" is taking a while to process.

The unfortunate effect I see is that the labels being loaded (let's say 100 labels) look like they're being placed one at a time.  While it does happen within a second, I would much prefer it to ALL LOAD first, then simply be put on at once.

I always thought that when you add the component everything is already done, and setVisible(true/false) just flicks the visibility on and off.  But due to this issue I see that perhaps that's not exactly how it works.

Here's my main method (I can provide more of my code if necessary):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                window.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JobInfoPanel jobInfoPanel = new JobInfoPanel();
                window.getContentPane().add(jobInfoPanel,
                        BorderLayout.CENTER);
                window.pack();
                window.setVisible(true);        
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

The thing that confirms to me that the problem lies in setVisible is if I add the following code after window.setVisible(true); the same problem arises:

```
jobInfoPanel.setPanelListVisible(false);
jobInfoPanel.setPanelListVisible(true);
```

I've tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work, including placing "jobInfoPanel.setPanelListVisible(false);" before window.setVisible(true).  The same thing occurs.

The only solution I think I am left with is somehow painting this panel off-screen and then moving it quickly to the correct location... if that makes any sense (I've read this as a suggestion on some pages, but this particular issue hasn't been brought up often).

Is there an easier way to do what I need?

Any and all help is much appreciated, thank you.

-Asaf

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you running this in the EventQueue? Why not just run it in your main method?

Comment: I'm not as experienced a java swing programmer and can't answer that question... I am running it this way because I copy/pasted that from some swing tutorial.

Comment: @Dave G, You're a 15 year Java developer and you're asking why Swing components are being modified on the `EDT`? What OP is doing in the main method is the correct approach. @Asaf, Don't worry, you're doing the right thing!

Comment: @Moonbeam: you are right, but don't be too harsh, guidance on this has changed over the years. here is an old article claiming it is ok: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html.

Comment: I am unsure what kind of response times you are seeing. If I take your code above, and add 100 JLabels to JobInfoPanel (using flow layout) it takes me ~150ms to draw the window and the setVisible() call is ~15ms of that. I have even tested your case with the turning jobInfoPanel on and off, and that is normally < 5ms.

Comment: @Sean, It probably has to do with querying the DB.

Comment: @Moonbeam my thinking as well, but the OP has referenced that setVisible is where they have determined the slowdown. So I am trying to determine why they have come to that conclusion

Comment: Well, the issue wasn't the time, it was just that visibly it didn't look nice seeing the labels loading that way... someone's answer below that I should have used a JTable instead is probably a better solution than the one I chose imo... but my boss wanted the panel to dynamically resize its height based on its width and this was easily accomplished using an extended flowLayout.

Comment: @Moonbeam - seriously take a chill and calm down - I was asking because the last time I did anything serious with Swing was nearly 10 years ago.  I haven't had to touch it as I've been primarily working with web technologies.  I asked because, I figured that the UI setup could be done in the main method no problem. The heavy lifting done by any composed object should be done out of the main thread using the EventQueue.  If guidance on this has changed over the years I apologize and that is why I asked the question the way I did.

Comment: Having looked at the article posted by @Nathan, I also would have to state that it was around the last time I did anything nearly related to Swing.

Comment: @Asaf, based on your comment above were you looking to make the painting a little less "serial" in that one label after another shows up? If that is the case, I think what you might want to do is look up how to disable the repaint for the duration that you are loading/adding components to display then re-enable/trigger the repaint after the operation completes.

Comment: Yes, this does also sound like it could be a solution.  I'm still trying to figure out why my answer worked though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate everyone's response, but was able to fix the issue by making a separate method which initialized this panel and calling it AFTER pack() in the main method, like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                window.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JobInfoPanel jobInfoPanel = new JobInfoPanel();
                window.getContentPane().add(jobInfoPanel,
                        BorderLayout.CENTER);
                window.pack();
                jobInfoPanel.createDriverListPanel();                   
                window.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I can't entirely explain why that works, but it did exactly what I wanted it to do.  Instead of seeing the labels appear one at a time, they all just pop at once.

Thank you again,
-Asaf

Answer (score 2):

> Panel that is loading labels in a flowlayout whose information is
>   taken from a database table's column

That's job for [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). You can find example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm), This way you can reduce time needed for painting tons of [JLabels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).

Comment: I think you're right, but unfortunately I am very new at this job, and since it was my boss who built the look of the component using Windows Builder Pro I feel a bit too embarrassed to change it now.

Comment: @Asaf if possible, leave such work for the whales, there is nothing really learned :-)

Comment: Haha, maybe when the job market feels a little better I will consider it.  This is my first real job post-college.

Comment: and this should not be a joke :-)